# Are questions about English allowed or is the site for learning Spanish only?

Tags: discusión, ámbito

I've seen several Spanish site that allow questions both about English and Spanish, making for a two-way flow of knowledge. Will site cater only to English speakers trying to learn Spanish and not the other way around? I assume translations in both ways are fine, but I assume questions that only concern English grammar are off-topic. Does this mean if the StackExchange network is going to have a site for Spanish Speakers to learn English it will be completely separate and not affiliated with this one?

Comment: Yo creo que para `Spanish Speakers to learn English` http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Questions **about** English are off-topic.

But there will be many cases where you need to compare some feature of Spanish with something in English. Be it translation or usage or anything. Most of these (except trivial single word translations) will be on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Questions that only concern English grammar or usage would be perfect for the [English StackExchange site](http://english.stackexchange.com). Otherwise, as long as the question involves the Spanish language and is within the scope of this site, it shouldn't matter whether the asker is a native English or Spanish speaker.